# How to create a blur effect for android wallpaper? (with illustrations)

Tags: android, blur, launcher, wallpaper

i'm newbie. Im creating a simple android launcher. i have a problem with blur for wallpaper. Wallpaper larger than phone screen. i want to blur a path of this wallpaper which is as large as screen. however, each time when I scroll my screen, the part of wallpaper appearing on the screen will blur. thank you so much.

Illustration: [image]

Comment: you do something at your end ??

Comment: Not clear. Do you want a **blur**, a **crop** or **both**?

Comment: when i want to open a dialog or view, the wallpaper have blur. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this repo:

https://github.com/romannurik/muzei

It is wallpaper app and it has blur.

Comment: The op wants to implement a Launcher nor a WallpaperService

Comment: @PhaniRithvij the link I've provided contains blur code and it's irrelevant either it's for a launcher or a WallpaperService.

Comment: The OP wants to blur the wallpaper that's being shown. And the wallpaper would most likely be shown using a flag in the android manifest. So an answer to "How to blur an image" won't be useful. And you provided the link to the repo as the answer which should be a comment instead. And muzei's blur implementation is not simple if you bothered to look at it [here](https://github.com/romannurik/muzei/blob/master/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/muzei/render/MuzeiBlurRenderer.kt). Thus your answer is not beginner-friendly and isn't an answer either. So it is relevant.